# EJB Transaction and Business Object

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions

I trying to start a new ejb transaction with:

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)

annotation in my service method. Everything  works fine, and inside my service a BusinessObject its called. When that businessObject throws a exception, it is propagated to the ejb and the transaction its rolled back.

My question is: can a make a businessObject method execute in a different transaction with the same annotation that ejb has?

example:

```
@Stateless
    public class Service {

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public int methodA(String name) {
        BusinessObject business = new BusinessObject();
        business.save(name);
    }
}

public BusinessObject {
    public void save(String name){
        doSomeStuff(name);   
        log(name);
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    private log(name){
        doSomeOtherStuff(name);
    }
}
```

Check the transaction Attribute on log method of my business Object... Thats a valid annotation? obviously, its out of the ejb, but the context is in a transacction already.

Thanks for the help!.

Comment: This transaction boundaries are implemented through interceptors and proxies. If you call the method without going through the interceptor, it won't work., since there won't be an interceptor to intercept the call

Comment: so the transaction annotation must exist only inside a ejb class to work properly?

Comment: There are two types of transactions in ejb. Container managed and bean managed. If the class is not and ejb then container does not manage it and nor does it manage itself. So the answer is yes it should be an ejb to work with ejb transaction boundaries.

Comment: yes, so as i understand the interceptors that take care of the annotation for handle transactionAttribute doesn't exist outside ejb context. So any annotated class with transactionAttribute that is not an ejb, simply wont work or in other words the annotation will be ignored/not handled.